# define a specific location to extract "residential" data from it

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm new at `OpenStreetMap` and `overpass-turbo` i did write a code to extract `residential` from the country of Qatar and it works fine but if I would like to define a specific location based on west, east, north, south location like what we do in OpenStreetMap

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“highway='cycleway' in qatar”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “qatar” to search in
{{geocodeArea:qatar}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “highway=cycleway”
  node["highway"="residential"](area.searchArea);
  way["highway"="residential"](area.searchArea);
  relation["highway"="residential"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

i tried to change the `{geocodearea:qatar}` to `{25.2552,51.5635,25.2433,51.5434}` but it didn't work
how can i define a manual location ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this code that helped me a lot

```
[bbox:40.7163,-73.8872,40.7283,-73.8710];
(
  // query part for: “amenity=cafe”
  node["highway"="residential"];
  way["highway"="residential"];
  relation["highway"="residential"];
);
out center;
```